# How to create a .NET C# ValueType Tuple dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dynamically-generated, valuetuple

I would like to create a value type tuple dynamically from say a collection of values.

Example: I have a given `IEnumerable<T>` and I would like to create a tuple based on that collection.

How can I achieve that?

[It seems that the access within a value type tuple can be achieved dynamically](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/365/accessing-tuples-at-runtime-using-reflection) but nothing indicates that the same can be done for the creation of a value type tuple.

On of my purposes would be to leverage the properties of the Equality and HashCode of such tuples like described in this [article](https://montemagno.com/optimizing-c-struct-equality-with-iequatable)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve? It is trivial to create value tuples dynamically; e.g. `(myInt, myString)`

Comment: @Douglas "dynamically from say a collection of values.". Let's say we have an array `a` of unknown length `l`, how can you create tuple `t` of length `l` based on `a`. About the use I gave one example of purpose that I would like to leverage.

Comment: That's not remotely the purpose of `ValueTuple`. If you just want to steal the code for implementing `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` over multiple values, [steal away](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/ValueTuple.cs#L263) -- it's not particularly complicated to adapt such code to work on collections. That's certainly a lot cleaner than trying to dynamically create `ValueTuple`s, which gets downright uncomfortable for more than 7 items. Doubtless there's also lots of libs implementing this one way or another (e.g. for unit testing).

Comment: It was one of my purposes, not the only one, other purposes include, curiosity, twisted reflection and whatnot.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret - Are you trying to do this so that you can see if two sequences of values are equal?

Comment: @Enigmativity no, not at all, I gave one example but I am just curious about the feasibility. There is something a bit redundant on a SO, is that when someone asks for X, often people willing to help will come with do you want to actually do Y(often cause that workaround for a different goal is easier)? While I just want to do X. I just want to see if it was possible to create value type tuple without hardcoding it. That's it

Comment: @EhouarnPerret - I think in this case you're starting with `W` and are asking for `X`, but `X` is more limiting than the original `W`.

Comment: It's a natural consequence of trying to head off prolonged discussions about [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Nothing malicious about it -- sometimes being helpful requires going a bit further than just answering the bare question. We can't smell from the question itself that you're just curious. The actual task of creating a `ValueTuple` of arbitrary size dynamically is interesting, but only precisely because the results would be impractical.

Comment: @Enigmativity it was an example of purpose since I know that on SO such questions without "practical" purposes rarely got answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question still isn't clear, but I assume you want to convert your `a` collection into a value tuple of the form `(a[0], a[1], a[2], …)`. This isn't supported through any built-in functionality. Furthermore, you would quickly run into limits, as .NET Framework only defines up to [`ValueTuple<T1, …, T7>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-7?view=netframework-4.7.2) – going beyond that would require you to construct unwieldy nested value tuples using [`ValueTuple<T1, …, T7, TRest>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-8?view=netframework-4.7.2) (e.g. `ValueTuple<T1, …, T7, ValueTuple<T1, …, T7, ValueTuple<T1, …>>>`).

If you're seeking to achieve collection equality comparisons, you should use an `IEqualityComparer<ICollection<T>>` instead. Here is a sample implementation from [`SequenceEqualityComparer`](https://github.com/Douglas-Williams/DogmaMix.Core/blob/master/Core/Comparers/SequenceEqualityComparer%601.cs):

```
public class SequenceEqualityComparer<TElement> : EqualityComparer<IEnumerable<TElement>>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TElement> _elementEqualityComparer;

    public SequenceEqualityComparer()
        : this(null)
    { }

    public SequenceEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<TElement> elementEqualityComparer)
    {
        _elementEqualityComparer = elementEqualityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TElement>.Default;
    }

    public new static SequenceEqualityComparer<TElement> Default { get; } = new SequenceEqualityComparer<TElement>();

    public override bool Equals(IEnumerable<TElement> x, IEnumerable<TElement> y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        if (x is ICollection<TElement> xCollection &&
            y is ICollection<TElement> yCollection &&
            xCollection.Count != yCollection.Count)
            return false;

        return x.SequenceEqual(y, _elementEqualityComparer);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<TElement> sequence)
    {
        if (sequence == null)
            return 0;

        unchecked
        {
            const uint fnvPrime = 16777619;
            uint hash = 2166136261;

            foreach (uint item in sequence.Select(_elementEqualityComparer.GetHashCode))
                hash = (hash ^ item) * fnvPrime;

            return (int)hash;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: For the fun of it, here's my implementation to your actual question, using reflection and recursion:

```
public static object CreateValueTuple<T>(ICollection<T> collection)
{
    object[] items;
    Type[] parameterTypes;

    if (collection.Count <= 7)
    {
        items = collection.Cast<object>().ToArray();
        parameterTypes = Enumerable.Repeat(typeof(T), collection.Count).ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        var rest = CreateValueTuple(collection.Skip(7).ToArray());
        items = collection.Take(7).Cast<object>().Append(rest).ToArray();
        parameterTypes = Enumerable.Repeat(typeof(T), 7).Append(rest.GetType()).ToArray();
    }

    var createMethod = typeof(ValueTuple).GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Create" && m.GetParameters().Length == items.Length)
        .SingleOrDefault() ?? throw new NotSupportedException("ValueTuple.Create method not found.");

    var createGenericMethod = createMethod.MakeGenericMethod(parameterTypes);

    var valueTuple = createGenericMethod.Invoke(null, items);
    return valueTuple;
}
```

Sample use:

```
var collection = new[] { 5, 6, 6, 2, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 8, 3, 6, 3, 7, 4, 1, 6 };
var valueTuple = CreateValueTuple(collection);
// result: (5, 6, 6, 2, 8, 4, 6, (2, 6, 8, 3, 6, 3, 7, (4, 1, 6)))
```

If you don't mind `Item8` being boxed, you could do away with reflection:

```
public static object CreateValueTuple<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    switch (list.Count)
    {
        case 0: return default(ValueTuple);
        case 1: return (list[0]);
        case 2: return (list[0], list[1]);
        case 3: return (list[0], list[1], list[2]);
        case 4: return (list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3]);
        case 5: return (list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4]);
        case 6: return (list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4], list[5]);
        case 7: return (list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4], list[5], list[6]);
        default: return (list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4], list[5], list[6], CreateValueTuple(list.Skip(7).ToList()));
    }
}
```

The difference is that the reflection-based method generates a result of type:

```
ValueTuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int,ValueTuple<ValueTuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int,ValueTuple<ValueTuple<int,int,int>>>>>
```

…whilst the switch-based method generates:

```
ValueTuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int,ValueTuple<object>>
```

In each case, there is a redundant single-component `ValueTuple<T>` wrapping the nested value tuples. This is an unfortunate design flaw of the `ValueTuple.Create<T1, …, T8>` method implementation in the .NET Framework, and occurs even using the value tuple syntax (e.g. `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, (8, 9))`).

```
public static ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, ValueTuple<T8>> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6, T7 item7, T8 item8)
{
    return new ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, ValueTuple<T8>>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, ValueTuple.Create(item8));
}
```

As canton7 mentions, you can work around it by using the `ValueTuple<T1, …, T7, TRest>()` constructor directly, as shown in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55239517/1149773).

Comment: For some reason it irks me that there's no simple, clean way of writing an expression for "the `ValueTuple` type with the highest generic arity", leaving us stuck with the magic constant 7. (I know that's not very rational since the whole thing should never be used anyway.) ``typeof(ValueTuple).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("ValueTuple`")).Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Length).Max() - 1`` does not make me happy. C# 9 better have meta-generic constructs, or something!

Comment: I like that last switch statement-based one! It doesn't matter that `Item8` gets boxed - it got boxed in the reflection-based solution as well.

Comment: Wait, no, the switch-based one isn't right. Try it with `new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }` and it creates a `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, (8, 9))`. This is because it creates a `ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, object>` not a `ValueTuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ValueTuple<int, int>>`. It doesn't look like there is a `ValueTuple.Create` overload which does this, either.

Comment: Hmm, looks like your first solution suffers this same problem, as well. You need to use `new ValueTuple<......>` for the one with `TRest`, not `ValueTuple.Create`. Not that it matters a jot for generating equality/hashcodes, but it's the principle of the thing...

Comment: @canton7: You're right about the redundant `ValueTuple<T>` wrapper; that is a surprising design flaw of `ValueTuple.Create`. It even occurs for the native syntax (`var valueTuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, (8, 9));`), so Microsoft apparently weren't too bothered by it. As for the `ValueTuple<T1, …, T7, object>` resulting from the switch-based method, yes, that's what I meant by "boxing". Equality comparisons still work (albeit slightly less efficiently), since `ValueTuple` overrides `Equals(object)`.

Comment: Ah I see what you meant with the boxing - not that the `ValueTuple<int, int>` was boxed in the first place, but that the box stays referenced.

Comment: @canton7: Exactly; that's a better description for it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the actual question, for anyone who's interested...

As others have said, **do not** do this if you simply want to determine whether two sequences are equal, or get the hashcode of two sequences. There are much better, cheaper ways of doing this.

It gets a bit involved. The BCL defines `ValueTuple<T>`, `ValueTuple<T1, T2>`, etc, up to `ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>`. After that, you need to use `ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>`, where `TRest` is itself a `ValueTuple` of some kind (and they can be chained like this).

```
public static class Program
{
    private const int maxTupleMembers = 7;
    private const int maxTupleArity = maxTupleMembers + 1;
    private static readonly Type[] tupleTypes = new[]
    {
        typeof(ValueTuple<>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,,>),
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = CreateTuple(new[] { 1 });
        var b = CreateTuple(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 });
        var c = CreateTuple(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 });
        var d = CreateTuple(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 });
        var e = CreateTuple(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 });
    }

    private static object CreateTuple<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> values)
    {
        int numTuples = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)values.Count / maxTupleMembers);

        object currentTuple = null;
        Type currentTupleType = null;

        // We need to work backwards, from the last tuple
        for (int tupleIndex = numTuples - 1; tupleIndex >= 0; tupleIndex--)
        {
            bool hasRest = currentTuple != null;
            int numTupleMembers = hasRest ? maxTupleMembers : values.Count - (maxTupleMembers * tupleIndex);
            int tupleArity = numTupleMembers + (hasRest ? 1 : 0);

            var typeArguments = new Type[tupleArity];
            object[] ctorParameters = new object[tupleArity];
            for (int i = 0; i < numTupleMembers; i++)
            {
                typeArguments[i] = typeof(T);
                ctorParameters[i] = values[tupleIndex * maxTupleMembers + i];
            }
            if (hasRest)
            {
                typeArguments[typeArguments.Length - 1] = currentTupleType;
                ctorParameters[ctorParameters.Length - 1] = currentTuple;
            }

            currentTupleType = tupleTypes[tupleArity - 1].MakeGenericType(typeArguments);
            currentTuple = currentTupleType.GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(ctorParameters);
        }

        return currentTuple;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's certainly better than what I was cooking up. As an exercise to the reader, try solving this with recursion. It's loads of fun. (For certain values of "fun".)

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code. Probably does the same as the code in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55239715/1300910), no?

Comment: Never mind, I see you're working around the maximum tuple members.

Comment: @huysentruitw try yours with `new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }`. Yours throws, mine (and @Douglas's) work.

Comment: @huysentruitw: it's what we call "this one goes up to 11".

Comment: Yeah just figured that out. I think someone could combine both snippets to create something neat. If we don't care about performance/memory, we could just make 2 item tuples, recursivly and get rid of the double for-loop. :)

Comment: @huysentruitw Depends how you interpret the question. Strictly speaking, `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)` is different to `(1, (2, (3, (4, (5, (6, (7, 8))))))`

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I'm doing this do generate a key in my EntityFrameworkCore mock library [here](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core-mock/blob/master/src/EntityFrameworkCoreMock.Shared/DbSetBackingStore.cs#L62).

But as pointed out by Douglas, the ValueTuple definitions are limited to 7 parameters, but for the usecase of the mock library, this is just fine.

Anyway, in essence, the code would look like this:

```cs
var valueTupleType = Type.GetType($"System.ValueTuple`{collection.Length}")
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"No ValueTuple type found for {collection.Length} generic arguments");

var itemTypes = collection.Select(x => x.GetType()).ToArray();
var constructor = valueTupleType.MakeGenericType(itemTypes).GetConstructor(itemTypes)
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("No ValueTuple constructor found for key values");

var valueTuple = constructor.Invoke(collection);
```